# Deleting activity in a Facebook Group

Tags: facebook-groups

Some of the admin activity is appearing in the timeline for our Facebook Group and when I click on the down-arrow, it only gives me the option to "pin" the post, not delete it from the timeline. Is there a reason why or a way around this?